# Warning for struct padding in Clang

Tags: c, padding

I created the following structure:

```
typedef struct  s_fct_printf
{
  char          flag;
  void          (*fct)(void*);
}               t_fct_printf;

static const t_fct_printf       flags[] =
{
  { 's', my_putstr_printf },
  //[...]
  { 'b', display_base_2 },
};
```

But when I compile with clang option `-Weverything`, I have the following warning:

```
warning: padding struct 'struct s_fct_printf' with 7 bytes to
      align 'fct' [-Wpadded]
```

I found the following solution :

```
typedef struct  s_fct_printf
{
  char          flag;
  void          (*fct)(void*);
  char          pad[7];
}               t_fct_printf;
```

But it's not solving the problem:

```
warning: missing field 'pad' initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
    { 'b', display_base_2 },
warning: padding struct 'struct s_fct_printf' with 7 bytes to
          align 'fct' [-Wpadded]
```

So I tried that:

```
typedef struct  s_fct_printf
{
  char          flag;
  char          pad[7];
  void          (*fct)(void*);
}               t_fct_printf;
```

But got the following errors:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char'
      with an expression of type 'void (void *)' [-Wint-conversion]
    { 'b', display_base_2 },
warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject
      [-Wmissing-braces]
    { 'b', display_base_2 },
warning: missing field 'fct' initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
    { 'b', display_base_2 },
error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
    { 's', my_putstr_printf },
```

The last solution I found was that, but I have read it's not optimized since the compilator does not packaging my variables anymore.

```
typedef struct __atribute__((__packed__))       s_fct_printf
{
  char          flag;
  void          (*fct)(void*);
}                                               t_fct_printf;
```

Is there a good solution?

Comment: You haven't stated the problem...

Comment: Well, my problem is that when I compile with clang, I have this warning: padding struct 'struct s_fct_printf' with 7 bytes to
      align 'fct' [-Wpadded]

Comment: This warning can be safely ignored and suppressed. Padding structures is a perfectly valid thing compiler often does. Unless you are relying on the specific layout, of course, which is not a good thing to do..

Comment: You should disable the padding warning; it is not useful for normal program code. It might be a better approach to read the lit of warning options and add the ones you want. That way you also know what they mean (which you would have found out, if you had read the docs, btw).

Comment: This is quite a good article: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef struct  s_fct_printf
{
  char          flag;
  char          pad[7];
  void          (*fct)(void*);
}               t_fct_printf;
```

is good for taking care of the padding issue. However, you'll have to change the way you initialize the array.

Use

```
static const t_fct_printf       flags[] =
{
  { 's', "", my_putstr_printf },
  { 'b', "", display_base_2 },
};
```

Otherwise, the compiler tries to initialize the member `pad` with `my_putstr_printf`, which is not what you want.

**Update**

You can avoid the hard coded number `7` for the size of `pad` by using:

```
typedef struct  s_fct_printf
{
  char          flag;
  char          pad[sizeof(void(*)(void))-1];
  void          (*fct)(void*);
}               t_fct_printf;
```

Thanks are due to @WeatherVane for the suggestion.

Comment: I was about to comment on the question, that the proposed padding in OP's first solution is on the wrong side of the function pointer member. But could the `7` be computed at compile time with `sizeof`?

Comment: But why want to pad it anyway? The compiler does that already. The compiler just informs you that it pads.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, Good question. I am guessing it has to do with coding practices adopted by a team.

Comment: Why care about padding at all? That warning is only useful if you are concerned about it and that is typically true only for few `struct`s (use `#pragma` around those). Even there, you better use packing (possibly with the warning to be completely safe). Also the `sizeof` approach does not necessarily generate the correct padding. e.g. `struct { uint8_t a; /*manual padding with sizeof*/ uint64_t b;}` will always add 7 bytes, although on e.g. 32 bit CPUs 3 would be sufficient. Better use `_Alignof(next_element) - (sizeof(previous_element)` (I'd, disable the warning, though)

Comment: Makeing the code less readable just to get the compiler to stop complaining is not a solution at all. Paddings in structs should only be used, if the struct is 0-packed, and some binary representation is required. In this case either disabling the warning completely or disabling the warning using a pragma should be applied. In most cases no one cares about the padding

Answer (score 6):

I gave your problem due consideration. I do not feel that adding a padding field is the solution. It clobbers the code and introduces potential future problems.

I also understand a quality requirement that all code should compile without warnings or errors. However, this warning is only informative and does not point to a possible error.

My advice would be to explicitly suppress this warning at those points where it occurrs and where the occurring is accepted. I would propose (using VC as example):

```
#pragma warning(disable:4123)
// The compiler will inform that padding will insert 7 bytes after flag,
// which will be unused. This is acceptable.
typedef struct  s_fct_printf
{
  char          flag;
  void          (*fct)(void*);
}               t_fct_printf;
#pragma warning(enable:4123)
```

I hope your compiler has a comparable mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are running on a 64-bit system. A `char` takes one byte and the compiler wants to let the function pointer start on a 64-bit (8-byte) boundary. Hence, it needs to pad 7 bytes after the `char` to align the function pointer.

The compiler just informs you about this (due to the implied option `-Wpadded`) but the code does not contain an error.